# Assign YAML array from input to key using `yq`

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm trying to take a YAML style array I get from an AWS command, and assign it to a key while updating my own YAML.

This represents what I have right now:

```
yq '(.HostedZones[] | select(.Id=="/hostedzone/ABC123")).ResourceRecordSets |= "'"$(aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "ABC123" --output yaml | yq '.ResourceRecordSets')"'"' -i route53.yml
```

This is how `route53.yml` looks like **before** I run the command:

```
HostedZones:
- CallerReference: abc-123
  Id: /hostedzone/ABC123
  Name: domain.name.com.
  ResourceRecordSetCount: 5
```

and this is how `route53.yml` looks like **after**:

```
HostedZones:
- CallerReference: abc-123
  Id: /hostedzone/ABC123
  Name: domain.name.com.
  ResourceRecordSetCount: 5
  ResourceRecordSets: |-
    - Name: a.domain.name.com.
      ResourceRecords:
        - Value: some.value.com
      TTL: 300
      Type: CNAME
    - Name: b.domain.name.com.
      ResourceRecords:
        - Value: some.value.com
      TTL: 300
      Type: CNAME
    - Name: c.domain.name.com.
      ResourceRecords:
        - Value: some.value.com
      TTL: 300
      Type: CNAME
    - Name: d.domain.name.com.
      ResourceRecords:
        - Value: some.value.com
      TTL: 300
      Type: CNAME
    - Name: e.domain.name.com.
      ResourceRecords:
        - Value: some.value.com
      TTL: 300
      Type: CNAME
```

As you can see there's a `|-` right after the key, and it seems like it is treated as multiline string instead of an array of maps. How can I avoid it and assign the array as a YAML array? When I tried manually assigning an array in the style of ['a', 'b', 'c'] and the update works as it should, adding a YAML array under the key, how can I achieve it with the output of the `aws` command?

Comment: Why is this question tagged `jq`?

Comment: @Cyrus Because a popular version of `yq` is just a wrapper around `jq`, so it uses the same syntax (and just calls `jq` after some preprocessing).

Comment: You shouldn't [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) into the code the data you want to append. Rather use appropriate means offered by `yq`. As you mentioned to be using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (which is the "popular version of `yq` [which] is just a wrapper around `jq`"), this would be using options like `--arg` or `--argjson` or `--argfile` (see [how to invoke `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq))

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `yq` is interpreting the output of the `$(...)` expression as a multiline strine is because you have quoted it; your `yq` expression, simplified, looks like:

```
yq 'ResourceRecordSets |= "some string here"'
```

The quotes mean "this is a string, not a structure", so that's what you get. You could try dropping the quotes, like this:

```
yq '(.HostedZones[] | select(.Id=="/hostedzone/ABC123")).ResourceRecordSets |= '"$(aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "ABC123" --output yaml | yq '.ResourceRecordSets')" route53.yml
```

That *might* work, but it is fragile. A better solution is to have `yq` parse the output of the subexpression as a separate document, and then merge it as a structured document rather than a big string. Like this:

```
yq \
  '(.HostedZones[] | select(.Id=="/hostedzone/ABC123")).ResourceRecordSets |= input.ResourceRecordSets' \
  route53.yml \
  <(aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "ABC123" --output yaml)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you can provide `jq` (and hence `yq`) multiple files on the command line, and then refer to the `input` variable (described in the [IO section of the `jq` manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#IO)). The above command line is structured like this:

```
yq <expression> <file1> <file2>
```

Where `<file1>` is `route53.yml`, and `<file2>` is a bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

This solution simplifies issues around quoting and formatting.

(You'll note I dropped your use of `-i` here; that seems to throw `yq` for a loop, and it's easy to output to a temporary file and then rename it.)

Comment: Using `input.ResourceRecordSets` directly would eliminate the need for invoking `yq` twice.

Comment: Good point! Updating the answer to match.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved it using a combination of larsks answer about the unnecessary quotes, and using `jq` instead of `yq` (no matter what I did, using solely `yq` wouldn't work) to assign the array to a separate variable before editing the YAML document:

```
record_sets=$(aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "ABC123" | jq '.[]')
yq '(.HostedZones[] | select(.Id=="ABC123")).ResourceRecordSets |= '"$record_sets"'' -i route53.yml
```